# String or binary data would be truncated error with weird data

Tags: sql-server

Just in the last couple of days, our processes have started to throw the error "String or binary data would be truncated" when the destination column does not match the source column.  Which is understandable, the weird part is this is what it returns as the exact message:

String or binary data would be truncated in table 'xxx', column 'yyy'. Truncated value: '滀˳.Ɛ...霶翽.ᜠ..힀䐈˷.....痨̛.潀þ.聠⣠͆.癠㘟þ.�翽.쁠͆.洀˳.㟠⣡͆.痨̛.叠Ἕ੯.訰䷿˳.뚠ᦞ̰.癠㘟þ.....␉翽.潠㘟þ.潀㘟þ.儘翽.﫰̚.'.

String or binary data would be truncated in table 'aaa', column 'bbb'. Truncated value: '᫐Ⱛ͎.È.....͡.礀þ.狀┒̜.È......⪘̫........痨䌯þ.瘸þ.瘐䌯þ.�ƪ...
㴃翽.........稰䌯þ.翽.Ѡ郎̫.......͡.⅀̫.㌀郎̫.'.

We do not have any of these characters in our data.  The example are from 2 different tables run by 2 different processes.  I can't actually figure out what specific data is causing the error - nothing appears to be too long and certainly no data with those characters.  If I fix the destination column size to match the source, the error goes away.

I swear it used to return the actual value that was too long.  Did something change recently in SQL?  Is this some kind of virus attempt?  Or is this totally normal behavior and it is just the first time I have seen it?

This is on MS SQL Server 2019

This is the type of query that causes the problem (no fancy SQL stmt)

```
INSERT INTO *desttable*  (columnname)
SELECT columnname 
FROM *sourcetable*
```

Where the source column is nvarchar(510) and the dest column is nvarchar(200)

Comment: What is the data in the actual column?  Is the column VARHAR or NVARCHAR?  if it is VARCHAR some characters may not be recognizable for that data type and thus convert them to what you are seeing.

Comment: the source and dest are NVARCHAR(#) - and the dest column is smaller (which I will fix).  No query will pull the offensive row - so I went through and looked at an entire table for any weird characters - nothing.   One of the times this happened was a field that is the username set by Azure (which would have character restrictions), another time it was a free-entry description field.

Comment: we think maybe it is reading memory outside of the column - but I have never seen this before

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Comment: I can't - I literally have no idea what data is causing this problem.  I am inserting data into a table using a select query - and the destination column is too short.  But I can't figure out where the string in the error message is coming from.  We are trying to do this exact step as a way to explain it to our Server Admin team.

Comment: What are you expecting from strangers on the internet that can't see your data?

Comment: I'd try a dataflow in SSIS

Comment: What `@@VERSION`? Did you install any CU that might be responsible for the change? (e.g, with a bug that prints out some random data in memory rather than the actual string)

Comment: Thi functionality to actually show the data being truncated is new and i think it's enabled by a trace flag only (or maybe you enabled verbose reporting in sql2019). Perhaps there is a bug in the implementation of the error message, it looks like it's messing up the encoding somehow but hard to say. if you do a regular test and try to insert some dummy string into a short table, does it behave similarily?

Comment: Version is 15.0.4178.1

Comment: I did the simple steps in this article (https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/getting-more-information-from-the-string-or-binary-data-truncated-error) and got a normal error message: String or binary data would be truncated in table 'dbo.StringInsertTest', column 'mystring'. Truncated value: 'this is mo'.

Comment: Are you using any product features that might be relevant to the bug if there is one? UTF8 collation? Dynamic data masking? Compression? Column store tables?

Comment: UTF8 collation is a very good guess! @OP, what's the actual data that's erroring for you

Comment: Server Collation??  It is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS  Where would i see if we are using UTF8 Collation?

Comment: I think @siggemannen comment is probably my "right answer" (new functionality plus a MS bug) - do you want to enter it as an one?